# How can I paginate in Mongoose without duplicates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an API for my site (using Node.js and Mongoose) and I would like to incorporate pagination in it. My problem is the following: if the page size is for example 15 and I make a request for the first page so it sends me the first 15 items ordered by date of creation but then what if before I make the request for the second page, 15 new items are created in the database, the returned data will be the same as previously if I just use a skip on mongoose.

Is there a way to avoid doublons with mongoose? What I have at the moment is an "exclude" parameter in the query so it excludes all items already loaded but I'm thinking if there are lots of loaded items, the URL might be very long and I'm not sure that's a good thing...

Is there a better way to do this or do I have to just leave it with the risk of having doublons?

Comment: That's an interesting problem!

Comment: Would you mind using the mongodb natvie driver?

Comment: Depends how much difference there is with mongoose because I've already got quite a good amount of code written using mongoose and it would be better if I could stay with mongoose so I don't have to re-write everything but if there's no other way then I might have to switch

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongoose-paginate-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2)

And to prevent any duplicates from returned documents, you can pass (last document id & limit)

And your query should be like :

```js
import { PaginateModel } from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

constructor(
private readonly _paginateModel: PaginateModel<any>
  ) {}

const query = this._paginateModel
          .find({ _id: { $lt: lastId } });
    this._paginateModel.paginate(query, { limit: 10 });
```

Comment: @Sae I updated the answer & code snippet, please let me know why this is wrong answer ?
because i already use it in my app & it's working fine as expected.

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake . Do you know how to do this with mongoose-paginate?  
"https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate"

Comment: @Sae I think it will be similar to mongoose-paginate-v2

Comment: Dose this actually work? I check the issue, said this is not [cursor-based](https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2/issues/41).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `skip` and `limit` function in which you can pass `min` and `max` value .

like in first page if you get 15 records values for min and max will be :

`min = 0` and `max = 15`

for page 2

`min = 15` and `max = 30`

Comment: I think this approach exactly does caused the duplicates